# Login and follow in Instagram with angular

Tags: angular, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to login into Instagram and follow the specific user directly from my angular web app. So, I want to know is there any API for login and follow in Instagram or is there any other way through which I can directly login into Instagram and follow a user from my angular web app?

Also if the above is not possible, is there any way to get a callback event in angular when a user follows any other user from the Instagram website?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly navigate the user into specific account by

`https://instagram.com/{username}`

following the above url.

but for getting callback as a response you may need to integrate instagram api's after creating a developer account and create app and make sync with api keys.

Comment: Thanks. I have already created a developer account, also I referred to the document of Instagram for the callback event, but I didn't find anything for it. Do you know how to get callback events if the user follows any other user in angular?